# how to export data from Login to profile page in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, authentication, react-router

I just want to send data (username,password,gender) from login Page to Profile page after doing the Authentication process  Here's my code could any one help

```
 <div className="d-flex  justify-content-center mt-5">
            {loginStatus=="Thanks For Logging In" ? 
            <Navigate to={
              {
                pathname: '/profile',
                state:
                {
                username: Username,
              password:'Password'
            }
          }
        } />
         :
<div> 
 Login Compoments
</div>
```

Comment: how to get data in profile page

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you add [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to your application and wrap your `<App />` entry point with the redux provider.

Redux has great documentation and gives you control from a single central source of truth.

Especially if you working in a team and if needed you could use [redux persistor](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to save pieces of data to local browser storage so that you don't lose state inside your component should you face a connectivity error. And as a bonus, there's a [browser plugin for redux](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) so that you can see your state changes and makes for an amazing development experience.

[Here is a link](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) to the documentation that will give you a stepping stone to get started

Happy coding =)